# query_posts - slightly more advanced query

Tags: query-posts

I'd like to edit the front page posts query to be slightly more advanced. Right now it excludes all posts in the Featured category. I'd like it to exclude the first 5 posts (or first n posts, really), but include the rest in the results.

Here is the current call:

```
<?php query_posts("cat=-".$GLOBALS['ex_feat'].",-".$GLOBALS['ex_vid'].",-".$GLOBALS['ex_aside']."&paged=$paged"); ?>
```

How would I edit this to include all featured posts as well, except the first 5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up asking this in a better way, and received an answer:

[Add a special filter link to All Posts in admin](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/43831/add-a-special-filter-link-to-all-posts-in-admin)

Answer (score 0):

See the [`offset`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Offset_Parameter) argument:

`...&offset=5...`

And avoid using global variables, and query_posts. Use the pre_get_posts action instead.

Comment: Can I set the offset of featured posts to 5, but leave everything else at 0?